# Как у блока сделать такую тень?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую тень, средствами css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc 0, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse, #999 0, #ccc 70%);
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо